# Regular expression for Japanese char with Alphabets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to add a Validation Rule to validate the Text either it should be any one of the following rules

- Japanese character (Any Japanese letter) => 北海道
- Alphabets (A-Z) => Kantname
- Japanese character with Alphabets =>   北海道AB

I written the below Regular Expression but its not working as expected

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$|[\u3000-\u303F]|[\u3040-\u309F]|[\u30A0-\u30FF]|[\uFF00-\uFFEF]|[\u4E00-\u9FAF]|[\u2605-\u2606]|[\u2190-\u2195]|\u203B/g;
```

If I tried the below its returning **TRUE**

```
console.log(pattern.test('北海道 <script>'));
```

Comment: Try `/^[一-龯a-zA-Z]+$/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using anchors in a wrong way: you need to merge all character classes into one single class and apply anchors to this superclass:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\u3000-\u303F\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\uFF00-\uFFEF\u4E00-\u9FAF\u2605-\u2606\u2190-\u2195\u203B]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GW3MFs/1)

```js
var re = /^[a-zA-Z\u3000-\u303F\u3040-\u309F\u30A0-\u30FF\uFF00-\uFFEF\u4E00-\u9FAF\u2605-\u2606\u2190-\u2195\u203B]+$/;
var strs = ['北海道AB', 'Kantname', '北海道', '北海道 <script>'];

for (var s of strs) {
  if (re.test(s)) {
    console.log(s, " matches the regex");
  } else {
    console.log(s, " does NOT match the regex");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes its Perfect to add some special chars just i added with \@\#\.. Thanks for this

Comment: You should not escape `@`, nor `#`. If you added them into the character class, add them like `[@#....]`